# Create fully notification android 12

Tags: android, custom-notification

I want to custom notification like [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOFfv.png). In android 12, my custom notification not is not fit the notification area width. How can I fix it? Here is my notification:

> ```
>     val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
>         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.img_app_logo)
>         .setCustomContentView(remoteViews)
>         .setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)
>         .setCustomHeadsUpContentView(remoteViews)
>         .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
>         .setAutoCancel(true)
>         .addAction(optimizeAction)
>     cancelAction?.let {
>         builder.addAction(it)
>     }
>     notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build())
> ```

Thanks

Comment: did you got any solution I'm having same problem in android 12... same code works fine upto android 11 but in android 12.

Comment: @SunilSapkota No, I still don't have the solution

Comment: Hi, I am just fighting the same, did you please find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You should change the `targetSdkVersion` from the `build.gradle` file to something below 31. (30 worked for me)

More information here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12